# How to reject a promise, if mysql query returns no records?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, reactjs, react-native

How to reject a promise, if mysql query returns no records?
I have tried something like results.length === 0 but it doesn't work. My promise is resolved with an empty array of records. How can i reject a promise, if sql query returns nothing(record is not found in the database)?

My function which should handle the request:

```
function Sres_login(pool, res, params) {
    const {ServerResponse} = require("./ServerResponse");
    const contentCreator = Sres_promise(pool, params);
    ServerResponse(contentCreator, res);
}



function Sres_promise(pool, {username, password}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const {query} = require("mysql");

        pool.query(`SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Login = '${username}' AND Password = '${password}'`, (error, results) => {
            if (error || results.length === 0) {
                reject("Niepoprawny login lub haslo");
            }
            else {
                console.log(results);
                resolve(results);
            }
        });
    });
}


module.exports = {
    Sres_login,
}
```

Server response:

```
function ServerResponse(contentCreator, res){

    let content = {error: null, message: null};

    return contentCreator
    .then((message) => 
    {
        content.error = false;
        content.message = message;
    })
    .catch((error) => { 
        content.error = true;
        content.message = error;
    })
    .finally(() => {
        res.send(content);
    })
}

module.exports={
    ServerResponse,
}
```

Edit:
[image]

Comment: What is the type of results variable?

Comment: It's an array of objects(records from mysql database). I edited my post and included a photo of this in my post.

Comment: Unhashed passwords in your `accounts` table? That's bad. Please fix it or we'll be seeing you on https://haveibeenpwned.com. .

Comment: Well, it's a test version. I'd rather prefer to know, why my promise is not being rejected, if an array is empty.

Comment: Nevermind, everything works correctly now. If someone finds it, restart all your environment(for me: android studio, android emulator, backend, generally i would restart everything just to make sure). For some reason, changes in code, or genereally state on android emulator sometimes are reflected, and sometimes are not